# Long caption with \listoffigures - breaklink and hyperref issue

Tags: floats, hyperref

I'm coming to the end of my thesis, and have decided to include `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` within my document. However, according to wikibooks:

> Problems with long caption and `\listoffigures` or long title
>
> There is an issue when using `\listoffigures` with `hyperref` for long captions or long titles. This happens when the captions (or the titles) are longer than the page width about 7-9 words depending on your settings). To fix this, you need to use the option breaklinks when first declaring:
>
> \usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
>
> This will then cause the links in the `\listoffigures` to word wrap properly.

When using this option, I presented with a warning telling me that I have enabled this option. Is there a way to stop `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` producing a number of bad boxes (overfull hbox) without introducing this warning?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Maybe you are already aware of this, maybe not, but it is worth mentioning that one can use `\caption[lof/lot entry]{rather long descriptive title in the document}`. This helps at first.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Am aware of the short caption option, but I still have captions that are longer than a single line and so need to be broken. I can add a MWE, however it seems a very general issue in that you'd just have \documentclass[12pt]{article} and usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref} in your preamble, followed by \begin{document} ... \end{document} (unless i'm missing something obvious)

Answer (score 2):

The warning is very correct. Setting `breaklinks` for drivers, which does not support this option, results in wrong link areas. If the warning would be removed,
then later the question would be asked, why the link areas are messed up.

If you cannot use a driver, which supports `breaklinks`, then there is a way to deal with the table of contents (and friends): Option `linktocpage` makes the page number instead of the chapter/section titles to links, then the latter can be broken across lines without link area problems.

Comment: processing such a file with "ordinary" latex won't break links regardless of specifying that with `hyperref`.  one needs to use pdflatex.